# Custom Linux distro - mono runtime not found

Tags: mono, embedded-linux, yocto

I am trying to add [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) to `core-image-minimal` for [P202RDB](http://www.nxp.com/products/microcontrollers-and-processors/power-architecture-processors/qoriq-platforms/p-series/p2020-reference-design-board:P2020RDB) custom Linux distro. Here is my `bblayers.conf` file:

```
# LAYER_CONF_VERSION is increased each time build/conf/bblayers.conf
# changes incompatibly
LCONF_VERSION = "6"

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BBFILES ?= ""

BBLAYERS ?= " \
  /home/testuser/QorIQ-SDK-V1.9-20151210-yocto/sources/poky/meta \
  /home/testuser/QorIQ-SDK-V1.9-20151210-yocto/sources/poky/meta-yocto \
  /home/testuser/QorIQ-SDK-V1.9-20151210-yocto/sources/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  /home/testuser/QorIQ-SDK-V1.9-20151210-yocto/sources/meta-freescale \
  /home/testuser/QorIQ-SDK-V1.9-20151210-yocto/sources/meta-freescale-internal \
  /home/testuser/QorIQ-SDK-V1.9-20151210-yocto/sources/meta-freescale-extra \
  /home/testuser/QorIQ-SDK-V1.9-20151210-yocto/sources/meta-mono \
  "
BBLAYERS_NON_REMOVABLE ?= " \
  /home/testuser/QorIQ-SDK-V1.9-20151210-yocto/sources/poky/meta \
  /home/testuser/QorIQ-SDK-V1.9-20151210-yocto/sources/poky/meta-yocto \
  "
```

Now, when I try to build image using `bitbake core-image-minimal`, I get following output from it:

```
Loading cache: 100% |##############################################################################################################| ETA:  00:00:00
Loaded 1496 entries from dependency cache.
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION        = "1.26.0"
BUILD_SYS         = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING   = "Debian-8.6"
TARGET_SYS        = "powerpc-fsl-linux-gnuspe"
MACHINE           = "p2020rdb"
DISTRO            = "fsl-qoriq"
DISTRO_VERSION    = "1.9"
TUNE_FEATURES     = "m32 spe ppce500v2"
TARGET_FPU        = "ppc-efd"
meta              
meta-yocto        
meta-yocto-bsp    = "(detachedfromb74ea96):ddf114933ccfc6e3ce51a10e8e8f95e514b73578"
meta-freescale    = "(detachedfrom7fb32a2):7fb32a20983a0ebd5503eb42e851550b0deb8679"
meta-freescale-internal = "(detachedfrom220bff8):220bff8b2030e5af7393b5870d74c6f0af0d76d1"
meta-freescale-extra = "(nobranch):ced26c806cb566b1400a2f4f26a94d8d44d13233"
meta-mono         = "daisy:f01b4f7a98d07abcf4c1f845c057199e112fb7d6"

NOTE: Preparing RunQueue
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 1248 tasks of which 1248 didn't need to be rerun and all succeeded.
```

It seems **mono repository is found**, then I prepare `SD card` using this image and it boots without problems on target board, however, `mono` command is not available. What am I missing?

Comment: Adding the mono layer does not add the mono package (s) to the core-image-minimal. What else have you done to add mono? Added it in your local.conf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
 IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " mono"
```

to your `local.conf`. Just adding a layer doesn't add any package to your image.

Even better, create your own image, and add `mono` to `IMAGE_INSTALL` in that recipe.

Comment: I did that, it worked, however, now `bitbake` complains with `**Error**: You must have 'libtool' installed to compile Mono.` and I **have libtools** installed on my host system (`Debian 8`).

Comment: Could you provide a link to a full error message?
Another thing, do you have `libtool-bin` installed? At least on Debian-based system, this is a separate package.