# Custom Linux distro (buidling mono) - aclocal failed

Tags: linux, mono, embedded-linux

I am working on custom `Linux` distro and the problems began with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41262487/custom-linux-distro-mono-runtime-not-found). I've overcame `libtool-bin` from that question, however, when I run `bitbake core-image-minimal`, I get following error:

```
Loading cache: 100% |##############################################################################################################| ETA:  00:00:00
Loaded 2402 entries from dependency cache.
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION        = "1.26.0"
BUILD_SYS         = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING   = "Debian-8.6"
TARGET_SYS        = "powerpc-fsl-linux-gnuspe"
MACHINE           = "p2020rdb"
DISTRO            = "fsl-qoriq"
DISTRO_VERSION    = "1.9"
TUNE_FEATURES     = "m32 spe ppce500v2"
TARGET_FPU        = "ppc-efd"
meta              
meta-yocto        
meta-yocto-bsp    = "(detachedfromb74ea96):ddf114933ccfc6e3ce51a10e8e8f95e514b73578"
meta-freescale    = "(detachedfrom7fb32a2):7fb32a20983a0ebd5503eb42e851550b0deb8679"
meta-freescale-internal = "(detachedfrom220bff8):220bff8b2030e5af7393b5870d74c6f0af0d76d1"
meta-freescale-extra = "(nobranch):ced26c806cb566b1400a2f4f26a94d8d44d13233"
meta-mono         = "daisy:f01b4f7a98d07abcf4c1f845c057199e112fb7d6"
meta-networking   
meta-python       
toolchain-layer   
meta-oe           = "(nobranch):214e1801d0efc38d3b6142bdc0d8e58ca593e34c"
meta-linaro-toolchain = "(nobranch):3f1933242062d1cf473d20b86fa4582963ff9441"

NOTE: Preparing RunQueue
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
ERROR: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at /home/testuser/QorIQ-SDK-V1.9-20151210-yocto/sources/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/mono-native/3.4.0-r0/temp/log.do_configure.7236)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/testuser/QorIQ-SDK-V1.9-20151210-yocto/sources/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/mono-native/3.4.0-r0/temp/log.do_configure.7236
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing python function sysroot_cleansstate
| DEBUG: Python function sysroot_cleansstate finished
| DEBUG: Executing shell function autotools_preconfigure
| DEBUG: Shell function autotools_preconfigure finished
| DEBUG: Executing python function autotools_copy_aclocals
| DEBUG: SITE files ['endian-little', 'common-linux', 'common-glibc', 'bit-64', 'x86_64-linux', 'common']
| DEBUG: Python function autotools_copy_aclocals finished
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_configure
| grep: configure.in: No such file or directory
| /home/testuser/QorIQ-SDK-V1.9-20151210-yocto/sources/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/mono-native/3.4.0-r0/mono-3.4.0/autogen.sh: line 125: mono/mini/Makefile.am: No such file or directory
| /home/testuser/QorIQ-SDK-V1.9-20151210-yocto/sources/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/mono-native/3.4.0-r0/mono-3.4.0/autogen.sh: line 126: mono/metadata/Makefile.am: No such file or directory
| Running aclocal -I m4 -I .  ...
| aclocal: error: 'configure.ac' is required
| 
| **Error**: aclocal failed. This may mean that you have not
| installed all of the packages you need, or you may need to
| set ACLOCAL_FLAGS to include "-I $prefix/share/aclocal"
| for the prefix where you installed the packages whose
| macros were not found
| NOTE: mono-native failed to autogen.sh
| sed: can't read acinclude.m4: No such file or directory
| WARNING: exit code 2 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at /home/testuser/QorIQ-SDK-V1.9-20151210-yocto/sources/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/mono-native/3.4.0-r0/temp/log.do_configure.7236)
ERROR: Task 735 (/home/testuser/QorIQ-SDK-V1.9-20151210-yocto/sources/meta-mono/recipes-mono/mono/mono-native_3.4.0.bb, do_configure) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 1872 tasks of which 1871 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
No currently running tasks (1240 of 1887)

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/testuser/QorIQ-SDK-V1.9-20151210-yocto/sources/meta-mono/recipes-mono/mono/mono-native_3.4.0.bb, do_configure
Summary: There was 1 ERROR message shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

I am trying to integrate [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) into custom image and I do not know, what is wrong now. I went to directory `~/QorIQ-SDK-V1.9-20151210-yocto/sources/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/mono-native/3.4.0-r0/mono-3.4.0` and ran `autogen.sh` by hand and it finished without errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the downloaded version of `mono` to `master` branch (version `4.8.0`) in it rebuilt without problems.